# null safety issue for getter with if-statment

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to retrive User data from sharedPreferances with code:

```
User? get user {
    String? u = sharedPreferences.getString("user");

    if (u == null) {
       return null;
    } else {
       return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(u));
    }
}
```

but I'm getting error **"The return type of getter 'user' is 'User?' which isn't a subtype of the type 'User' of its setter 'user'."**

I want to be able to return null but compiler just doesn not allow me  because of null safety.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?:/

Comment: can you show the content of  "User.fromJson" method and User class

Comment: You have a corresponding setter that takes `User` instead of `User?`, and the types of a getter and setter are expected to match.  See https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#getter_not_subtype_setter_types and https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/misc/c/74VgbBxVXoM?pli=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the type of your setter is `User` which is not nullable, but your getter is `User?` which is nullable, i.e. the types are different. And the compiler insists that the setter and getter should have the same type.

```dart
class User {
  
}

class Foo {
  
  set user(User user) {
    
  }
  
  User? get user {
    return null;
  }
}
```

So, the fix is to use both for the setter and the getter a nullable or a not nullable type.

```
  set user(User? user) {
    
  }
  
  User? get user {
    return null;
  }
```

[Try it on Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3fa98be333397703a4ad2681f4188752&null_safety=true)